# Why does the datetime format in DataFrame table spyder and python console different

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, spyder

I'm  trying to change my non `datetime` type column into type `datetime`and format `2020-03-31` . The original format and type is `31-Mar-20` and object. I tried to change the type into `datetime` after formatting it into `2020-03-31` but somehow if i change it into type `datetype`, in my `dataframe` it's always including the `hh:mm:ss` **but when i check it in the console it's already `datetype` and without** `hh:mm:ss`. Why is this happening?

When i check it,this is my `DataFrame` table in my Variable explorer tab in Spyder

[image: my dataframe]

This is when i check it in the console

```
covid.date
Out[156]: 
0    2020-03-02
1    2020-03-03
2    2020-03-04
3    2020-03-05
4    2020-03-06
5    2020-03-07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly convert those `datetimes` to `dates` by extracting the date part with:

```
covid['date'] = covid['date'].dt.date
```

Then they should lose the `time` part, and become `datetime.date` instead of `datetime`.

Now, you'll notice that the column is actually of type `object` (e.g. when using `covid.info()`). `pandas`, in fact, doesn't have `datetime.date` as a standard data type. So it treats the whole column as storing `object`s indeed.

But if you access the single element you'll notice it is a `datetime.date`. So for example you can do stuff like:

```
covid['date'].iloc[0].year
# Out: 2020
```

and get meaningful results, as opposed to trying to do that on a string.

If you want to get for example the `year` of every element in that column you will have to resort to `apply` (as you cannot call `.dt` anymore), something like:

```
covid['year'] = covid['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Comment: well if i assign it `covid['date'] = covid['date'].dt.date` it turns back `dtype: object`

Comment: Look at the edit, see if this clears a bit of doubts :)